# Selenium-webdriver/phantomjs with Nodejs not working on reboot - Linux

Tags: linux, node.js, selenium, phantomjs, cron

Well, I'm scraping a site with **Selenium-webdriver/phantomjs** using Nodejs in this way:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var By = require('selenium-webdriver').By;
var until = require('selenium-webdriver').until;
var phantomjs = require('selenium-webdriver/phantomjs');

var app = express();
var driver = new phantomjs.Driver();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var user = req.query.user;
    var pass = req.query.pass;

    driver.get('https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/'); // The site I'm requesting (:

    // remove read-only attribute
    driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('Password').removeAttribute('readonly')");
    // inputs
    driver.findElement(By.id('LoginName')).sendKeys(user);
    driver.findElement(By.id('Password')).sendKeys(pass);
    // button
    driver.findElement(By.name('Login')).click();
    // wait for the title
    driver.wait(until.titleIs('List'), 5000);

    driver.findElement(By.css('td[class*="nav"]')).getText().then(function(text) {
        console.log(text);
    });

    driver.quit();
});

var server = app.listen(5000, function() {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port
  console.log('Api listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)
});
```

If I type on the terminal:

`forever --pidFile /var/run/app.pid -a -l /var/log/node/app.log start /home/user/node-apps/myapp/app.js`

and then in a browser I type:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/?user=a_user&pass=a_pass
```

the script returns properly the answer (text) from  the site.

But I need that this app may be available when I reboot the server, so I edited my crontab and added this:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/sudo -u root -H /usr/local/bin/forever --pidFile /var/run/app.pid -a -l /var/log/node/app.log start -c /usr/local/bin/node /home/user/node-apps/myapp/app.js
```

But this time, things are not working as they should. The script returns an error, saying:

`Error: Waiting for title to be "List" Wait timed out after 5006ms`

But if I stop the app by typing: `forever stop 1` and then I type the fisrt command (I mean: `forever --pidFile /var/run/app.pid -a -l /var/log/node/app.log start /home/user/node-apps/myapp/app.js`), the app works again.

Some ideas on why the app does not works when I reboot the server?

**EDIT: 1**

I have tried this method obteining some data from a site that does not require authentication, and when I reboot the server, the app works. And also I have tried with other sites that authentication is require and I got the same problem.

My idea is that the problem is with sites that require authentication. Why? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have internet connection during the first run after reboot?

Comment: Well good question, but I waited five minutes after the server started, and the problems persists. I edited my question with some clues.